# Is the image of the exponential map of a complex semisimple group Zariski open?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a semisimple complex algebraic group. Is the image of the exponential map
$$\exp : \mathfrak{g} \to G$$
Zariski open in $G$?

Comment: No, in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{C})$ the matrix $-I_2$ is exponential of the traceless diagonal matrix $(i\pi,-i\pi)$, but if $N$ is any nonzero nilpotent matrix, $-I_2+N$ is not exponential of any traceless matrix.

Comment: In fact this is the only exception: the image of $\ \exp\ $ consists of those matrices which are not of the form $-I_2+N$, with $N$ nilpotent $\neq 0$.